# Como fazer login e manter a sessão?

Tags: php, html, login, popup

Eu tenho uma pagina *HTML* com um botão para administração antes tem um login *popup* e o *php* desse login para está noutro ficheiro. E eu queria saber como fazer para se ele aceitar o login conseguir ir sempre carregar naquele botão sem ter que fazer sempre login.

Eu sei que é preciso fazer isso com *session* mas eu não sei fazer e eu não consigo perceber dos sites em que já fui.

Alguém me pode dizer um site que me explique como *session* funciona ou mesmo explicar?

Aqui está o seguinte código para o login *popup*:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('a.login-window').click(function() {
  var loginBox = $(this).attr('href');
  $(loginBox).fadeIn(300);
  var popMargTop = ($(loginBox).height() + 24) / 2; 
  var popMargLeft = ($(loginBox).width() + 24) / 2; 
  $(loginBox).css({ 
   'margin-top' : -popMargTop,
   'margin-left' : -popMargLeft
  });
  
  $('body').append('<div id="mask"></div>');
  $('#mask').fadeIn(300);
  return false;
 });

 $('a.close, #mask').live('click', function() { 
 $('#mask , .login-popup').fadeOut(300 , function() {
 $('#mask').remove();  
 }); 
 return false;
 });
});
```

```html
<div id="login-box" class="login-popup">
  <div id="fechar">
    <a href="federados.html" class="close"><img src="images/close_pop.png" class="btn_close" title="Close Window" alt="Close"></a>
  </div>
  <form method="post" class="signin" action="php/login.php">
    <fieldset class="textbox">
      <label class="username">
        <span>Nome de Utilizador:</span>
        <input id="username" name="username" type="text" autocomplete="on" placeholder="Username" required>
      </label>
      <label class="password">
        <span>Palavra-Passe:</span>
        <input id="password" name="password" type="password" placeholder="Password" required >
      </label>
      <br/>
      <input type="submit" class="submit_button" value="Iniciar Sessão"/>
      <p><a class="forgot" href="#">Forgot your password?</a></p>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</div>
```

PS: O código não funciona pois é um *popup* apenas funciona se clicar no botão.

Comment: Não podes fazer isso só com HTML precisas de uma linguagem no servidor como PHP que já vi que usas. O PHP tem *session's*

Comment: Da uma olhada [aqui](http://www.devmedia.com.br/criando-sessao-para-login-no-php/27347)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eu costumo usar `Cookies`, `LocalStorage` ou o `SessionStorage` para fazer esse tipo de coisa.

O `LocalStorage` e o `SessionStorage` são recursos do HTML5 e são bem simples de se trabalhar. Se você quiser que a sessão morra após fechar o navegador basta usar o SessionStorage, caso contrário use o LocalStorage que mesmo fechando o browser o usuário permanecerá logado.

O grande problema desses dois storages é que navegadores antigos não o suportam totalmente, então você precisa avaliar se seu usuário não vai usar um IE7 da vida...

Os Cookies podem ser úteis se você quiser um meio termo entre o SessionStorage e o LocalStorage, já que é possível definir uma "validade" para o Cookie.

Uma vantagem do Cookie é que ele é um recurso suportado por navegadores mais antigos, só é um pouco chato para ler e gravar valores. Eu costumo usar um Cookie.js que encontrei na internet, me avise se precisar que posso incluir na resposta.

Enfim, você pode pesquisar um pouco mais sobre cada recurso que te passei e definir qual será a melhor estratégia.

Então você basicamente poderia fazer o sistema de autenticação da seguinte forma:

1. Ao se autenticar, o servidor gera um token ou algum tipo de identificação única pra você e o retorna;
2. Você pega este retorno e o grava num cookie, localstorage ou sessionstorage;
3. Sempre que o usuário for navegar, você deve recuperar este valor, enviar para o servidor e caso seja válido concluir a navegação, caso contrário mandar pra tela do login ou de erro.
4. Ao fazer o logoff basta apagar os valores do sessionstorage, localstorage ou cookie e invalidar o token ou identificador único no servidor.

Espero ter ajudado.

**EDIT**

O PHP oferece a global $_SESSION que também pode te ajudar. Então fica a seu critério.